# Is it to possible add placeholder text for link fields?

Tags: 7

Been trying to add placeholder text for my link fields.

Using hook_form_alter to add the attributes. It works fine with text fields

```
$form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Your First Name' );
```

But not able to get it work with link fields

```
$form ['field_twitter_link']['und'][0]['#attributes']['value']['placeholder'] = t( 'Your Twitter profile link' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this in

```php
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'mytheme_after_build'; 
}

function mytheme_after_build(&$form, &$form_state){
  $form['field_twitter_link']['und'][0]['url']['#attributes']['placeholder']=t('my new');
  return $form;
}
```

Taken from here https://drupal.org/node/1002560

Comment: Works great... feel bad i didn't check the issue queue properly. Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: I have a image field in the same form, when i upload an image it shows an error call to undefined function theme_after_build() and the upload fails.

Comment: @jack its working on my side. i am altering node form though.

Comment: Hey human... I used it for user register form & was getting the alert. I changed #after_build to #pre_render, everything works good now.